# vim autocomplete directory name

Tags: vim

When I'm using filename autocompletion in command-line mode, how do I do select the current option to autocomplete?

For example, let's say I want to open the file `~/dev/myproject/foo.c`

I start by typing:

`:e ~/d`<kbd>tab</kbd>

And I hit tab a couple of times until I see

`:e ~/dev/`

What do I press next to get vim to autocomplete the directories within `~/dev/`?

If I hit <kbd>enter</kbd>, vim will open a buffer with the directory listing, which is not what I want.

I can hit `/` and then tab, but then I get an innocuous but aesthetically displeasing double-slash in my path:

`:e ~/dev//`<kbd>tab</kbd>

I can also hit "m", and then tab, which will work:

`:e ~/dev/m`<kbd>tab</kbd>

But what if I didn't remember that the next directory started with "m"?

How do I tell vim in the above example that "dev" is the autocomplete option that I want, and then to continue to do autocompletion for the next part of the path?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:h wildmenu`

> `<Down>`      - in filename/menu name completion: move into a subdirectory or submenu.

Comment: The solution is to use an arrow key? That seems... wrong, somehow.

Comment: @LorinHochstein I know, it is weird. But this is default behavior. Nothing stopping you to map `<Down>` to something else in cmd mode

Comment: @LorinHochstein: Hey, I didn't write it, don't blame me :p

Comment: Don't drink the Kool-Aid, there's nothing wrong with the cursor keys.